# Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive In an equation for ‘convertTuple’: Patterns not matched: []

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function that Convert my list of lists of Int to a list of Tuples containing the items to display.
For example:
`[[43525,5,2],[7455,3,4],[25545,7,5]] --> [(1,43525,5),(2,7455,3),(3, 25545.7)]`

But i get this warning :
`Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive In an equation for ‘convertTuple’: Patterns not matched: []compile(-Wincomplete-patterns)`

My function :

```
convertTuple :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
convertTuple (x:xs) = zipWith (curry (\x -> (fst x,head (snd x), snd x!!2))) [1..] (x:xs)
```

What is the cause of the warning ?

Comment: As the error says, your `convertTuple` function, does not handle the case of an empty list.

Comment: The warning states: "Patterns not matched: []". Handle that case. You probably do not need to match against `x:xs`, just take any list instead. Also, using `curry (\x -> ...)` and then `fst/snd` seems to be complicated. Why not `zipWith (\a b -> ...)` ? Or even `zipWith (\a [b1,b2] -> ...)` if you are sure the list contains exactly two items.

Answer (score 2):

Your `convertTuple` only works for *non-empty* lists. Indeed, `convertTuple []` will not work since `(x:xs)` only pattern matches with *non-empty* lists with `x` the first item of the list, and `xs` the remaining items. You however do not need such pattern, you can simply use `xs`.

But furthermore your function contains some anti-patterns. For example you use another variable `x` that is more locally scoped, creating confusion between the the two variables. You can work with:

```
convertTuple :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
convertTuple = zipWith (\i (a:b:_) -> (i, a, b)) [1..]
```

Although this still can result in problems if a sublist of the list contains less than two elements. You thus might want to pattern match only if it contains *at least* or exactly two elements, for example with list comprehension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

convertTuple :: [[Int]] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
convertTuple xs = [ (i, a, b) | i <- [1..] | (a:b:_) <- xs ]
```

Comment: `!!2` is the third element, not the second. From the example input given, though, that seems like maybe a bug in the original code?

Comment: @DanielWagner My suggestion is that the example provided by Elfi is hand written. Look at the last tuple. We can see `25545.7` instead of `25545,7`. Still the example suggests that the behavior expected is the one Willem provided. Elfi probably made an error thinking that `!!2` is the second value (which is a natural assertion IMHO).